# C# How to access a class reference using a string

Tags: c#, class

**So, I have spent about 3 hours so far trying to find a solution**
But, it is hard to understand the topics so high above my current knowledge.

**QUESTION**
If I have a base-class called *Spell* , and Sub-Classes such as *HolySmite* or *DivineBuff* , is there any possible way to access those classes by using a string?

**MORE INFORMATION**
I have a bunch of spells, ALL of them have simple variables such as *refreshTimer* or *manaCost*
I am trying to use one simple method called *CastSpell()*
This Method has about 30 lines of code such as:

- is it time yet to cast spell?
- do we have enugh mana to cast the spell?
- did we complete casting the spell (because it took 10 seconds to cast it)?
  *

Currently, I am having to manually do all 30 lines of code *multiplied* by all the spells that I have, so far 30. It is very repetitive and makes it difficult read.  
**EXAMPLE Right now VERSUS what I want to do:**

```
// this string can be any spell, I have 30 spells so far but will be adding more
    string spellName = "HolySmite";

    // Currently, I am having to write 30 lines of code attached below, and then I have to repeat the same damn thing for 30 spells
    // Lets just use only 1 line of code as an example...
    if (spellName == "HolySmite")
    {
        Spell.holySmite.castingNow = true;
    }

    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< INSTEAD HOW CAN I GENERICALLY ACCESS THE CLASS FROM A STRING >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    Spell.spellName.castingNow = true;
    // Obviously, spellName does not exist inside the class. I just want to access the class called "HolySmite"
    // -- which is the variable stored in string spellName;
    //
    // Someone suggested using a Dictionary GET/SET inside the class:
    //
    //public class Spell
    //    {
    //        public Dictionary<string, SpellInfo> Spells = new Dictionary<string, SpellInfo>()
    //        {
    //             { nameof(HolySmite), new HolySmite() },
    //             { nameof(DivineBuff), new DivineBuff() }
    //         }
    //    }
    //    
    // However, using Dictionary prevents me access the subClass properties such as: refreshTimer, radius, damage, etc, etc, etc, etc
    //
    // THERE MUST BE SOME OTHER WAY!
```

HERE IS THE CLASS DEFINITIONS

```
public string spellName;

// My nested/inherted class
public abstract class SpellInfo
{
    public float timeToCastSpell;
    public float refreshTimer;
    public int manaCost;

    public float lastTimeCompleted;
    public float lastTimeAttempted;
    public bool castingNow;
    public abstract void Action();
}
// DERIVES from SpellInfo
public class HolySmite : SpellInfo
{
    public float radius;
    public int damage;

    public override void Action()
    {
        Debug.Log("Casting HolySmite");
    }
}
public class DivineBuff : SpellInfo
{
    public override void Action()
    {
        Debug.Log("Casting DivineBuff");
    }
}

public class Spell 
{
    public static HolySmite holySmite = new HolySmite();
    public static DivineBuff divineBuff = new DivineBuff();
}
```

Comment: Put the method on the base class and call it from sub classes. or make some sort of helper class and put the method there and use it in all your classes, or use [Strategy design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy) if you want to do it right. I think your last chose should be Reflection

Comment: Usually when you need to find a property using a string you resort to [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) but there is something unclear in your data structures. Can you show how the classes Spell and HolySmite are defined?

Comment: I think your "base" class it not an actual base class, you don't seem to be using inheritance at all. I think `Spell` should be an abstract class with the generic logic, and then make `HolySmite`, etc. inherit from it and implement/update whatever it needs. Why do you need to get the class from its name in the first place? You may want to also check the Factory design pattern.

Comment: I will update to include full class definitions....

Answer (score 0):

Consider re-writing your spell class so that instead of having everything in a big long list of if statements, you use an interface to say a spell can act upon a target:

```
interface ISpell
{
    void CastOn(Player target);
}
```

Then your actual concrete spell class would look like:

```
class HolySmite : ISpell
{
    //other properties
    private int Damage = 15;

    public CastOn(Player target)
    {
        target.Health -= Damage;
    }
}

class DivineBuff : ISpell
{
    //other properties
    private int Resistance = 0.1;

    public CastOn(Player target)
    {
        target.Resistance += Resistance;
    }
}
```

Then, only the `CastOn` method needs to know about all the properties of the spell, and you can use a dictionary like you were recommended:

```
Dictionary<string, ISpell> Spells = new Dictionary<string, ISpell> 
{
    {nameof(HolySmite), new HolySmite()},
    {nameof(DivineBuff), new DivineBuff()}
};
```

Then, when you cast a spell, you simply say

```
var spellName = "HolySmite";
Spells[spellName].CastOn(myTarget);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.... Another person also suggested that I use a dictionary. However, I lost the ability to access the properties within the class. In your example: Ispell class has other variables for which HolySmite inherit such as: castingTime, refreshTimer, etc, etc..

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track, you just need to expand the capabilities of your abstract class.  Perhaps add a `CanCast` method?  Only the `Action` and `CanCast` methods should need to know the properties of the spell.

Comment: Also, consider that all spells might have a radius, it is just sometimes `0`.

Comment: Beware that a dictionary will always return the SAME object. That's why I suggested you check the Factory design patter instead, which will give you a new object each time.